# Simply-Connected Regions and Phragmen-Lindelöf Theorem 

Tags: cv.complex-variables

It's easy to see that the Phargmen-Lindelöf theorem from complex analysis can be generalized to non-simply-connected regions. Namely to regions $G$ with the property that for each $z \in \partial_\infty G $  there is a sphere $V$ in $\mathbb{C}_\infty $  centered at $z$  such that $V \cap G$ is simply connected.

The problem is that I can't think about any example of non-simply connected regions that have this property and of simply-connected regions that don't have this property...

Does the exterior of a unit ball can be considered as an example of non-simply connected region that don't satisfy the property above?
What about regions that do satisfy this property?

BTW - $ \partial _ \infty $ is the boundary of $G$ with the boundary at infinity (and $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ is the Riemann-Sphere ) .

Thanks in advance

Comment: A sphere in $C^\infty$? What's that?

Comment: It's $C$ with infinity... 

Comment: Firstly, there are a lot of results in complex analysis labeled "Phragmen-Lindelöf Theorems". It might be useful here to indicate which Theorem you are refering to.... Secondly, I'm not sure I understand the question... Doesn't an annulus, for example, satisfy the property? 

Comment: Of course...but what about unbounded regions? 


Comment: The exterior of the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ is contractible and so is simply connected. 

Comment: By "a sphere V in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$" did you mean a circle, i.e. the boundary of a disc?

Comment: For an example of unbounded non simply-connected region which satisfies your property, just take the complement in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ of two disjoint closed disks...

Comment: The question makes no sense as stated.
Examples of simply and multiply connected regions with the
stated property, or without it are abundant.
"Phragmen-Lindelof" is not a theorem but a Principle. There are 100's
of theorems based on this principle. I think the topic should be
closed, unless the author can restate his question clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Phragmen-Lindelof theorem has nothing to do with simple or multiple connectedness.
The general formulation is the following. Let D be an region on the Riemann sphere.
Let $w_0$ be a boundary point of D. Suppose that u is a subharmonic function in D which is
bounded from above. Suppose that $$\limsup_{z\to w} u(z)\leq 0$$ for all boundary points
$w$ of $D$, except $w_0$. Then $u\leq 0$.

One point $w_0$ can be replaced by any closed set of zero logarithmic capacity.
But the original argument of Phragmen and Lindelof was for one point, and $u=\log|f|$ where
$f$ is analytic.

For the proof, assume first that $D$ is contained in the unit disc, and $w_0=0$. Apply
the Maximum principle to $v=u+\epsilon\log|z|$. You obtain that $v\leq 0$.
Now fix $z$ and let $\epsilon\to 0$. Generalization to arbitrary $D$ is trivial.